# Is interface inheritance the right thing to do here, and why does it not work?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I'm implementing some type (`MyType` in the example below) which has a `Collection` property. Inside `MyType` I don't really care what kind of collection this is. The only thing I care is that it implements `IEnumerable<String>` and `INotifyCollectionChanged`. How would I implement the `Collection` property with these restrictions?

Here is what I've tried:

I created a new interface:

```
interface INotifyEnumerableCollectionChanged<T> : IEnumerable<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged {}
```

and made the `Collection` property in `MyType` of type `INotifyEnumerableCollectionChanged<String>`. This seems to work inside `MyType`. It looks like i can enumerate over that collection and register the `CollectionChanged` event.

But I can't set this property to a collection (`MyCollection` in the example below), even tough `MyCollection` implements both `IEnumerable<String>` and `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

The compiler says:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'InterfaceInheranceTest.Program.MyCollection' to
>   'InterfaceInheranceTest.Program.INotifyEnumerableCollectionChanged'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)

What is the right way to do this?

Here is the full example code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace InterfaceInheranceTest
{
    class Program
    {

        interface INotifyEnumerableCollectionChanged<T> : IEnumerable<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged {}

        class MyCollection : IEnumerable<String>, INotifyCollectionChanged
        {

            IEnumerator<String> IEnumerable<String>.GetEnumerator()
            { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

            System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

            public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
        }

        class MyType
        {
            private INotifyEnumerableCollectionChanged<String> _Collection;

            public INotifyEnumerableCollectionChanged<String> Collection
            {
                get { return _Collection;  }
                set
                {
                    _Collection = value;
                    _Collection.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(_Collection_CollectionChanged);
                    foreach (var item in _Collection)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            void _Collection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var collection = new MyCollection();
            var type = new MyType();
            type.Collection = collection;   // compiler doesn't like this!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class needs to implement `INotifyEnumerableCollectionChanged<T>`.

```
    class MyCollection : INotifyEnumerableCollectionChanged<string>. 
                         IEnumerable<string>, INotifyCollectionChanged
    {

        IEnumerator<String> IEnumerable<String>.GetEnumerator()
        { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    }
```

This is needed because the variable you use(`_collection`) is of type `INotifyEnumerableCollectionChanged<T>`. However, your class - `MyCollectionChanged` does not implement this interface, so can't be assigned as a reference to the variable.

Comment: Ok that compiles. But why is this needed? It already implements `IEnumerable<String>` and `INotifyCollectionChanged`. And `INotifyEnumerableCollectionChanged<T>` does not really add anything to them.

Comment: @RobertHegner - You are defining the type of the variable you are using to be `INotifyEnumerableCollectionChanged<T>`. Your implementation does not implement this interface, so can't be used as a valid reference to it.

Comment: Ok thanks for your solution and the explanation! I will accept in 4 minutes... :)

Comment: Just a small correction. In this example `MyCollection` is not a generic type, so we need to replace `T`with `String` or it won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

You created a new interface but you don't use it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace InterfaceInheranceTest
{
    class Program
    {

        interface INotifyEnumerableCollectionChanged<T> : IEnumerable<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged {}

        class MyCollection : INotifyEnumerableCollectionChanged<String> // Use your interface
        {

            IEnumerator<String> IEnumerable<String>.GetEnumerator()
            { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

            System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

            public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
        }

        class MyType
        {
            private INotifyEnumerableCollectionChanged<String> _Collection;

            public INotifyEnumerableCollectionChanged<String> Collection
            {
                get { return _Collection;  }
                set
                {
                    _Collection = value;
                    _Collection.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(_Collection_CollectionChanged);
                    foreach (var item in _Collection)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            void _Collection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var collection = new MyCollection();
            var type = new MyType();
            type.Collection = collection;   // compiler doesn't like this!
        }
    }
}
```

Defining same methods do not mean it's the same type.